# Control.Invoke method not returning

Tags: c#, .net-4.0

I'm trying to parallelize my code to make it run faster. So far, it's been all headaches and no results.

I want to update several DataGridViews at the same time :

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
        () => updateDgv1(),
        () => updateDgv2(),
        () => updateDgv3()
    );
```

I have tried using the easy (but probably not optimal) way recommended everywhere on the web (like here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171728(v=vs.85).aspx ).

```
private void updateDgv1() {
    /* some stuff */

    assignValue(this.dgv1, colPos, rowPos, value); /* in a loop */
    }

    delegate void AssigneValueCallback(DataGridView dgv, int columnPos, int rowPos, string valeur);

    public void assignValue(DataGridView dgv, Form form, int columnPos, int rowPos, string value)
    {
        if (dgv.InvokeRequired)
        {
            AssigneValueCallbackd = new AssigneValueCallback(assignValue);
            dgv.Invoke(d, new object[] { dgv, columnPos, rowPos, value });
        }
        else
        {
            dgv[columnPos, rowPos].Value = value;
        }
    }
```

The main thread gets stuck at "Parallel.Invoke(...)" call, waiting for the other threads to finish.

The threads created by "Parallel.Invoke(...)" get stuck at this point:

- mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle
  waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity,
  bool exitContext)
- mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int
  millisecondsTimeout, bool
  exitContext)
- System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle(System.Threading.WaitHandle
  waitHandle)
- System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(System.Windows.Forms.Control
  caller, System.Delegate method, object[] args, bool synchronous)
- System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate
  method, object[] args)
- etc

Why are they stuck?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you're calling `Parallel.Invoke` from the UI thread. If so, that's the problem.

`Parallel.Invoke` blocks until all the calls finish... which means you're blocking the UI thread. The tasks you're starting *can't* complete, because `Control.Invoke` blocks until the call on the UI thread has finished - so your subtasks are waiting for the UI thread to become available in order to update the UI, but your UI thread is waiting for all the subtasks to finish.

You *could* just fix this by using `BeginInvoke` instead of `Invoke` (and you may want to do that anyway) but it's fundamentally a bad idea to use `Parallel.Invoke` in a UI thread, precisely because it blocks.

Comment: Would System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(Action) work, or would I run into the same problem?

Comment: @PierreGardin yes Task.Run(Action) would work as long as you don't await it in the UI thread.

Comment: @PierreGardin: Yes, that would work - because calling `Task.Run` doesn't block to wait for the task to complete.